# Sqoop incremental lastmodified

Tags: sqoop, bigdata

I am having a accounts table in mysql db.

it has around 19654 records.I used sqoop to import the table data in HDFS.It created four files in HDFS with data evenly distributed

then i executed below sql statement on DB

```
update accounts set modified = now() where acct_num in (1,2,3,4) ;
```

Then i executed below sqoop tool

```
sqoop import --table accounts --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre 
--username training --password training 
--incremental lastmodified 
--check-column modified --last-value '2014-03-18 13:29:47.0' 
--merge-key acct_num --target-dir /accounts/
```

After the above completed it created only one file with around 10 entries only.Does not even include new timestamp value.

I was just trying to update the rows which have  new timestamp. Can anyone help?

Comment: any help on above question?